# Will Enabling TLS 1.2 and disabling older protocols on Windows Servers have any impact on desktops?

Tags: tls, pci-dss, compliance

I want to know what the impact would be if I were to enable TLS 1.2 on Windows Servers and disabled older protocols. I enabled TLS 1.2 on my Windows 7 Laptop manually running the Microsoft Fix It script and it broke my VPN connection, but that's for another thread.

Comment: it depends on the clients accessing your servers. This can help: https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you only enable new protocol, then there is no impact for existing applications as long as you do not disable others. SSL/TLS protocols in Windows are implemented side-by-side and one protocol do not affect other protocols. But if you disable any other protocol, applications may fail if they explicitly rely on a disabled protocol.

Comment: So, if we truly wanted to disable older protocols all other applications will need to be able to talk on TLS 1.2 or else it will not work. Would it be safe to say older protocols must remain enabled on Domain Workstations internally and disabled on the servers?

Comment: If you disable older protocols on servers, then clients with older protocols will fail if they do not support TLS 1.2. On servers you need to maintain a full range of protocols supported by clients.